# Apache proxy to forward guacamole

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-proxy

I'm running a Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit server, on which I have some headless VirtualBox VMs running. In the past I have just forwarded the ports to access the VMs manually, but I want to use Guacamole to consolidate things. I let apache act as a proxy for just about every service on my server, and configs like these:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName dynmap.address.net
    ServerAlias dynmap.address.org
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8123/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8123/
</VirtualHost>
```

work just fine, but this config for guacamole (which is based on instructions from http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/installing-guacamole.html) does not seem to work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName rdp.address.net
    ServerAlias rdp.address.org

    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/guacamole/ max=20 flushpackets=on
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/guacamole/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /guacamole /
</VirtualHost>
```

Upon accessing the ServerName, I get a generic "500 Internal Server Error", and /var/log/apache2/error.log just adds this line:

```
[warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

My googling thus far says this means that the proxy modules aren't loaded, but I've confirmed that proxy, proxy_http, and proxy_html are all loaded.

EDIT: Realized I had the wrong port on ProxyPassReverse, but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you activate the proxy_ajp module in apache? a2enmod proxy_ajp

Comment: Make sure you actually have an AJP connector listening on 8009.

Comment: Your apache is complaining about not being able to handle ajp:// protocol. So you can change your proxy pass to perform http:// (instead ajp) or enable proxy_ajp as @user130356 stated.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you provided, it looks like this in your config:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/guacamole/ max=20 flushpackets=on
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/guacamole/
```

Should actually be this:

```
ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/guacamole/ max=20 flushpackets=on
ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/guacamole/
```

You've got some extra slashes hanging around causing problems.

(Note, This depends on if you are using this inside a VirtualHost or Location tag).

Comment: Unfortunately I've long since given up on this, and switched to using RDP-over-SSH for this, I can't test this solution now.